# How to unpack or fetch a value of a nested variable stored in Azure DevOps Build Piplines' Variables group?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

Is it possible to use variable inside a variable in Powershell script with Azure Pipelines variables?

**SCENARIO**

1. Two variables are set in Azure Pipelines Variable group - `DeploymentCredentials`

   a. `DeployUATApiPassword = "123456"`

   b. `DeployPRODApiPassword = "789654"`
2. Another variable is set in the Variables section of the pipeline as `DeploymentEnvironment`
3. At runtime, the value of the `DeploymentEnvironment` variable is set as either `UAT` or `PROD`
4. Based on the enviornment, I want to fetch the password which is stored as a variable, defined in the variables group. At runtime, it should work something like...

   ```
   # setting the value of the variable to UAT
   Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DeploymentEnvironment]UAT"
   ```
5. Now `DevelopmentEnvironment` variable has the value `UAT`, In another step, I want to fetch the Password for the UAT deployment environment, which is only known at runtime.

   ```
   # I want to get the Password 
   # The following works! but not useful for me, UAT is hard-coded!!
   $deployPwd = $(DeployUATApiPassword) # works! but not useful for me, UAT is hard-coded!!

   # I want to get the Password
   # the following doesn't work, I only know the environment at runtime
   # Replaces the inner variable to `DeployUATApiPassword`
   # Raises an error, DeployUATApiPassword : The term 'DeployUATApiPassword' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet...
   $deployPwd = $(Deploy$(DeploymentEnvironment)ApiPassword) 

   # All the following didn't work either, but no error...
   Write-Host $('Deploy$(DeploymentEnvironment)ApiPassword')     # Output: DeployUATApiPassword
   Write-Host $($("Deploy$(DeploymentEnvironment)ApiPassword"))  # Output: DeployUATApiPassword
   Write-Host { 'Deploy$(DeploymentEnvironment)ApiPassword' }    # Output: 'DeployUATApiPassword'
   Write-Host { Deploy$(DeploymentEnvironment)ApiPassword }      # Output: DeployUATApiPassword
   Write-Host { $(Deploy$(DeploymentEnvironment)ApiPassword) }   # Output: $(DeployUATApiPassword)
   ```

Similarly, I tried to fetch the pwd in several ways, nothing worked.
For instance, one of the ways was to create another variable `DeployApiPassword` and I did set the value of the variable to `Deploy$(DeploymentEnvironment)ApiPassword`. No luck in this either...

```
$deployPwd = $(DeployApiPassword) # Output: DeployUATApiPassword
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

I want to fetch the password from one of the variables which is set in a variables group. The password variable name contains the deployment environment. Deployment environment is only set at runtime.

```
    # I know something is wrong with the following, but that's how I want to run.
    $deployPwd = $(Deploy$(DeploymentEnvironment)ApiPassword) 

    Write-Host $deployPwd # output: *** (of course, the pwd is hidden, but at least it fetches)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables set in Azure Pipelines Variable group would be used as environment variables in PowerShell task. So, basically, you need to get the value as :

```
$environment = $env:DeploymentEnvironment
$deployPwd = $env:DeployUATApiPassword
```

At the same time, as your want to dynamically get the password based on the environment, you may try the following:

```
$environment= $env:DeploymentEnvironment

Write-Host "Deployment Environment is " $environment

$realName = $("Deploy${environment}ApiPassword")
$pwd = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable($realName)

#I used UAT password, check it here
Write-Host $pwd.Equals("123456")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: If the string is opened (not secret) then the solution works. If mark the value of the variable as secret (by clicking on the lock next to it) then it does not fetch anything and `$pwd` is `null`

Comment: @wafers secret variables (encrypted variables and key vault variables) cannot be accessed directly in scripts - instead they must be passed as arguments to a task.  So, pass both secrets to powershell task, and you will be able to use either one you wanted in the secret.

Comment: @wafers May I know if your issue was solved? Do you have any other questions here?

Comment: well, I did not want to use the conditional logic to implement what i was looking for, but had no choice. If the same thing works for non-secret stuff, then what's wrong returning the secret value through the same way? That's returned anyway using the full string. I think it's broken implementation by Microsoft or Azure.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the value returned by `'Deploy$(DeploymentEnvironment)ApiPassword'` is a string type, however `$()` accepts a variable not a string.

In the [secret variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#secret-variables) official document, it says the secret cannot be referenced directly like normal variable. You have to manually explicitly map them in using the **Environment** section.

You will need to use `if statement`. And in the **Environment Variables** sections
Map the secret variables to variables `UATpassword` and `PRODpassword` and Then refer to them in the scripts using `$env:UATpassword`

[image]

From below log, we can see the password is retrieved in the script.

[image]

Comment: the solution above fetches the values of the variables if the value is open string. If it's a secret value, the password is empty/null. That's what was happening when I tried yesterday.

Comment: You are right, if it's a secret. the password is empty. I checked [how to secrets variable in script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#secret-variables). It says the secret cannot be referenced directly like normal variable. You have to manually explicitly map them in. I updated above answer.