# Update Azure DevOps build file

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, yaml, azure-powershell

I would like to update the module version of powershell file, I used Yaml/Powershell commands and was able to change the module version number but now I want to save my changes to the file location variable called fileLocation I don't know how I could save the changes I made to this .psd1 file. Current Yaml script is:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master

variables: 
  versionNumber: '1.0.$(Build.BuildNumber)'
  installModule: Install-Module -Name PowerShellGet -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force -Verbose
  data: Get-Content -Path James.Artifactory.psd1
  fileLocation: James.Artifactory.psd1
  versionUpdate: Update-ModuleManifest -Path James.Artifactory.psd1 -ModuleVersion "$(versionNumber)"

steps:
  #Remove or commentout installModule after running it once
  #- pwsh: $(installModule)
  - pwsh: $(versionUpdate)
  - pwsh: $(data)
  - pwsh: Get-Content -Path $(fileLocation)
  - pwsh: Out-File -FilePath $(fileLocation)
```

Comment: You should check in to the master branch the powershell file with your changes. Checking in to master will trigger the build and the build will have access to the files in the branch, including the powershell file. Did you check in the file?

Comment: I checked the master branch but nothing has changed except for the .Yaml file. I want the .psd1 to change

Comment: I'm trigger the code to run in the master branch

Comment: Is the psd1 file not already in source control? If it is, you should pull it down, edit the powershell file, commit your change, and push it back to origin master. When you do that, the build will be automatically triggered, which will then use the updated psd1 file (as long as you check it back into same location in file structure). I assume you're using git for source control. There are a lot of resources online for how to use git if you need help.

Comment: I have hundreds of .psd1 files that need to change I cant really do it to each individual one. I have to automate it. Also the .psd1 is in source control the whole time I', writing Yaml/Powershell commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can run git command in powershell script to commit the changes to your repository.

First you need to go the **Repositories** under **project settings**. Click **Git Repositories**, in the **security** page, click plus(+) and search for group **{your project name} build service({your org name})** and click to add it, and In the **access control summary page**, grant contribute and read permission. Please check below screenshot.

[image]

Then configure your yaml file to clean source and a[llow script accessthe system token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#allow-scripts-to-access-the-system-token) by using `checkout`. Below script is just an example.

```
pool: default

steps:

- checkout: self
  clean: true
  persistCredentials: true

   - powershell: |
    cd $(System.defaultworkingdirectory)
    git checkout -B master

    New-Item -Path '$(System.defaultworkingdirectory)\newfile366.txt' -ItemType File 

    git add .
    git commit -m "Update"
    git push origin master
```

Above script run `git checkout -B master` to checkout master branch. And I create a new file with  `New-Item`  command. Then I commit the changes and push to my azure repos.

> Note: I tested both on micrsoft-hosted agent and self-hosted agent. I only work out to run above git command on self-hosted agent. I always got **NativeCommandError** on Microsoft-hosted agent. Please [create your self-hosted agen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops)t to run your yaml pipeline, if you get the same error.

_

> Update:

Above git commands will commit changes to your master branch, and it will trigger another build if you enable CI build. You can disable CI build from the **Triggers**

Click the 3 dots and choose Triggers.

[image]

Then check **override the yaml ...** and **Disable continuous integration**

[image]

Comment: Lol for some reason the pipeline fails the first time then it runs again by it self and passes and keeps repeating. Any ideas ?

Comment: You need to disable the Continuous Integration build, for the git command will commit changes to your master branch, and it will trigger another build. Please check my update.

Comment: How can I add access token to the push of new changes? I currently have ***git push https://{PAT}@dev.azure.come/example*** but the PAT is hard coded is there a way to do Sysytem.ACCESSTOKEN on a specific token that was newly created. Like I have 3 tokens how does the system choose which token to use ?

Comment: System.Accesstoken is a PAT generated by the server for the service identity “Project Collection Build Service (account)”.  It is not the PAT generated from UI by yourself.  If you define `persistCredentials: true` for `- checkout` in yaml. This will allow script access the system token.  And If you want to use your self-created PAT, you can define a secret variable and assign its value to the PAT. And use it in your script. You can check my answer to [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59669787/how-to-unpack-or-fetch-a-value-of-a-nested-variable-stored-in-azure-devops-build).